# Classifying a Vector of Numbers to Categories in Matlab

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, I have a 1x2000 variable called `NewRatings` that contains only integers from 1 through 8.

I want to replace every value in this variable with a category name corresponding to its number.

The categories are `{'AAA','AA','A','BBB','BB','B','CCC','Default'}` in a 1x8 cell variable called `Ratings`. So I want to convert every instance of 1 to AAA, every instance of 2 to AA, and so on.

I've tried using ordinal:

```
NewRatings = ordinal(NewRatings, Ratings)
```

but this gives me the error

> CATEGORYNAMES and VALUESET must have the same length.

I have 8 possible values and 8 categories so I don't understand what the issue is. I've used these in the past with similar data for similar problems with no issues. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use your `newRatings` variable to index into your `Ratings` cell array of strings

```
newRatings_strings = Ratings(newRatings);
```

As for why `ordinal` doesn't work, it's likely because every value between `1` and `8` isn't represented in `newRatings`. You can check this with `unique`

```
unique(newRatings)
```

If you really want to use `ordinal` you could get the `Ratings` that correspond to the unique values in `newRatings`

```
ord = ordinal(newRatings, Ratings(unique(newRatings)));
```

Comment: For future reference, do you have any insight as to what I was doing incorrectly with the ordinal?

Comment: @beeba Updated with an explanation